# Unable to hit RESTful endpoints when uploading to Azure

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to upload a basic RESTful API following this [springboot tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). Basically, I have an endpoint `/greeting` which returns a json `{"id":1,"content":"Hello, World!"}`. Here is the request in code:

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template,  name));
}
```

This works perfectly fine when I run on a local server, but fails when I upload to my Azure App Service. I am not sure where things are going wrong and could use some help.

I am using Eclipse with the Azure toolkit and I am using a maven project. I publish to Azure by right clicking the project -> Azure -> publish as Azure Web App.

When the publish completes and I try to go to my `/greeting` endpoint on the Azure server, I have a 404 error. If I include a blank html page, the response I get from Postman is simply the contents of the html file, rather than the json that I want to return.

My expected result is to get that json back and I could use some advice.

Comment: What port is your app trying to listen on?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I'm not sure what you mean. This is a hosted server on Azure. I am not setting any port nor listening for any port when I try to hit the endpoint.

Comment: I mean, you said you are deploying to a Web App (which is not the same as deploying to a VM). With a Web App, only ports 80 and 443 are accessible externally, and you need to listen in on the port provided to you by the environment. You cannot, for example, open a listener on port 8888. So what I'm asking is, how is your software configured at initialization, to decide what port to listen to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just downloaded the sample code from the [springboot tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) you mentioned and tried to deploy it to my azure web app service.It does works for me.

Please refer to my steps and check if you missed something.

Step 1: Use `mvn package` to bulid the `JAR` package in the directory under which the pom.xml file is located. (Here is `E:\Downloads\gs-rest-service-master\gs-rest-service-master\complete` for me)

[image]

Step 2：Then you could see the `JAR` package in the `target` folder.

[image]

Deploy it to root `wwwroot/` on KUDU with `web.config` file.

***web.config:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
        arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar&quot;">
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please make sure that the `jar` package name configured in `web.config` is the same as the uploaded jar package name!

[image]

Step 3: Please make sure `ApplicationSettings` matches your project such as `jdk version,tomcat version`.

[image]

Step 4: Restart your app service and access the url : 
`https://<your app name>.azurewebsites.net/greeting`

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! I was missing the web.config file. I did not see that kind of file mentioned in any of the tutorials I tried to follow.